# Selecting Rows Where Conditions Match A Single Row?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, inner-join

I have two tables that are connected via a Foreign Key. In table A I'm trying to get all the rows where the data in the time column is greater than or equal to the table B start column and where the data in the time column is less than or equal to the table b end column. I was thinking that an inner join might work for this, however, the results are not what I expected. It is returning some data but they are repeating themselves.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT * FROM columnA
INNER JOIN columnB
ON columnA.time >= columnB.start
OR columnA.time <= columnB.stop
```

Am I looking at this wrong? Is an inner join even the right way of collecting this data?

**UPDATE:**

Actually tableA's Foreign Key is connecting to the Primary Key on tableB. Anyways I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.time >= tableB.start
AND tableA.time <= tableB.stop
```

The reason I didn't do what you did for the on is because the data has been in the database for a couple years now and I just recently added the column with the foreign key. So that column doesn't have any data in it yet. That's why I'm querying it so I can know which columns to update with the information. It returned the data to me but also returned other data that didn't meet the requirements.

Comment: Are you saying that using AND did help, or didn't help?  If it didn't help, could you post some sample data that demonstrates what went wrong, along with the results you want/expect?

Comment: It helped, actually now that I think about it I'm asking my question wrong. Row one of tableB has a start and stop time. What I am wanting to do is select the data in tableA that is greater than or equal to the time in the start time of the first row and less than or equal to the stop time of the same row. Sorry, didn't realize how I was wording my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the solution by adding a WHERE to match it the data in the exact row I was looking for. Here is my solution:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.timetag >= tableB.start
AND tableA.timetag <= tableB.stop
WHERE tableB.id = "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must join them using the columnName which defines their relationship and put the condition on the `WHERE` clause. (*not on `ON` clause*)

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM    tableA a
        INNER JOIN tableB b
            ON a.colName = b.colName  -- colName is the column that links 
WHERE   a.`time` >= b.`start` OR      -- both tables.
        a.`time` <= b.`stop`
```

Comment: There is no *requirement* to move the time conditions to the where clause.  The problem is the `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do your join using the foreign key, and then filter out the results that don't match your criteria.

```
Select * from TableA
Inner join TableB on TableA.Key = TableB.Key
Where TableA.time >= TableB.Start
Or TableA.time <= TableB.Stop
```

As a rule, I always keep W3Schools' sql page close at hand.  It's the best quick reference for SQL functions I might have forgotten and need a quick refresher on.  Also a great place to learn.

Comment: @JohnWoo I have to point out that none of the errata at that link refer to any of w3schools SQL content...

Comment: I can't speak to any of their other tutorials, though I do remember a few inaccuracies in some of their SQL content.  That was the vast minority, however, and if you keep your head on a swivel and make the F1 key one of your best friends, it'll do MUCH more good than harm.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM columnA a 
INNER JOIN columnB b ON a.joiningColumn = b.joiningColumn
WHERE a.time >= b.start
OR a.time <= b.stop
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question...

```
where the data in the time column is greater than or equal to the table B start column  
  AND  
where the data in the time column is less than or equal to the table b end column
```

Yet your query has...

```
columnA.time >= columnB.start  
  OR  
columnA.time <= columnB.stop
```

Combined with the note from others, about joining using the foreign key...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TableA
INNER JOIN
  TableB
    ON  TableA.PK    = TableB.FK
    AND TableA.time >= TableB.start
    AND TableA.time <= TableB.stop
```